# Cpanel Provide Seprate panel (filemanager and database admin for) shared linux hosting

Tags: cpanel, shared-hosting, addon-domain

i have linux shared hosting plan. i have many addon domains in it. my client want cpanel id passowrd so he can upload file manage database and tables in it.  is there any open source php script which i can install and give permission of use file manager and database part of only his domain.

thank you

Update (i need php based filed manager and database manager which i can install in my server and gave access to my client to access file manager and database)

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done as you state in the question. Many factors are not known, the most important of which is what your web hosting company will allow. You could provide the name of your web host, that may help someone working on an answer. But, this may be best answered in a different stack, like http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: my client just want file manager(not FTP) and database admin  is there any opensource php script which i can upload on my server and it gives access to him to upload view and delete file and manage table in database  like

Comment: for example Adminer 4.2.2 is php open source script used for manage database mysql